# Needed help to converting mssql functions into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Could anyone help me to solve issues with converting MsSQL to MySQL? It gives a syntax error.

**Original Mssql function:**

```
CREATE  FUNCTION StrToNum (srt1 varchar(250))  
RETURNS real AS  
 BEGIN 
DECLARE t real
IF srt1 IS NOT NULL and ISNUMERIC(srt1)=1 and PATINDEX('%,%',srt1)=0 and 
PATINDEX('%e%',srt1)=0
SET t=CONVERT(Money,srt1)
ELSE
SET t=NULL
RETURN t
END
```

**i tried like this as mysql**

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE  FUNCTION StrToNum (srt1 VARCHAR(250))   
RETURNS REAL DETERMINISTIC  
BEGIN   
DECLARE t REAL;  
IF srt1 IS NOT NULL AND srt1 > 0 AND POSITION('%,%' IN srt1=0) AND POSITION('%e%' IN srt1=0)  
THEN SET t=CONVERT(Money,INT);  
ELSE  
THEN SET t=NULL; END IF;  
RETURN t;  
END IF;  
END $$  
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: What is DELMIMITER$$? Add ';'. Then try to change Sql Server functions with alternative MySQL functions.

Comment: It's not `DELMIMITER`, it's `DELIMITER` - the extra `M` you have in the fourth position is probably a big part of your syntax problem. There is no `M` following the `L`; remove it.

Comment: Mark Byers i;ve updated my question. 
Devart Delimiter is not Problem. i created couple of function using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should parse:

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE  FUNCTION StrToNum (srt1 VARCHAR(250))   
RETURNS REAL DETERMINISTIC  
BEGIN   
DECLARE t REAL;  
IF srt1 IS NOT NULL AND srt1 > 0 
    AND POSITION('%,%' IN srt1=0) 
    AND POSITION('%e%' IN     srt1=0)  
THEN SET t=CONVERT(srt1,signed);  --(1)
ELSE  
 SET t=NULL; END IF;              --(2)
RETURN t;   
END $$                            --(3)
DELIMITER ;                       --(4)
```

I'll break it down for you:

- `CONVERT()` takes `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` as target types. `INT` doesn't work. (1)
- You brought forward a error from your CONVERT() syntax in mssql; you used `Money` instead of `srt1` (1). The reason for the confusion is that `CONVERT()` in MSSQL and MySQL have their parameters reversed.
- `ELSE` doesn't need (or accept) a `THEN` keyword after it (2)
- You had an extra `END IF` before the final `END$$` (3)
- `DELIMITER ;` requires a space (4)